# Node.js asynchronous functions not working

Tags: node.js, async-await

I have a function (lets call it f1) that calls another function (lets call it f2) inside it. The issue is that f2 is supposed to return a parsed json file output. But it always return undefined.

```
async function f1(){
    var customerDataArray = []
    fs.readdirSync(jsonFolder).forEach(file => {
        var temp = path.extname(file)
        if (temp == '.json'){
            customerDataArray.push(file)
        }
    });
    
    let templateFiles = customerDataArray
    console.log(templateFiles)
    
    for(let tfc=0; tfc < templateFiles.length ; tfc++){
        let fileName = templateFiles[tfc]
        let filePath = './fashion/test/' + fileName
        const templateJSON = await f2(filePath)
        console.log(templateJSON)
    }

    console.log(templateJSON)
}

async function f2(filePath) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error reading file from disk:", err);
          return;
        }
        try {
          const customer = JSON.parse(jsonString);
          return customer
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Error parsing JSON string:", err);
        }
      });
  }
```

You can ignore the other details of the file. I am able to display the parsed file in f2 using console.log(customer). But when it is returned to f1, temmplateJSON is undefined.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix and match callback-based async with promise-based (`async`/`await`) async.

Generally, you can [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) callback-based functions, but for `fs`, there's [`fs/promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promises_api) already (since Node 10).

Your code can thus be simplified to something like this. It won't read the files in parallel, though; if you had very many files, it'd be easy to cause "Too many open files" without adding something like `p-queue` or `p-limit` into the mix.

```
const fsp = require("fs/promises");

async function f1() {
  const files = await fsp.readdir(jsonFolder);
  const customerDataArray = files.filter((f) => path.extname(f) == ".json");

  for (let i = 0; i < customerDataArray.length; i++) {
    const filePath = "./fashion/test/" + templateFiles[i];
    const templateJSON = await f2(filePath);
    console.log(templateJSON);
  }
}

async function f2(filePath) {
  const content = await fsp.readFile(filePath, "utf8");
  return JSON.parse(content);
}
```